# Is it correct to place import not on top of file?

Tags: python, flask

I found in Flask [examples](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/) next code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import yourapplication.views
```

Is it's correct to place import not on file header?

Comment: define "correct"

Comment: You can import wherever you want as long as you do not use something before you import it. It is sometimes even the only good solution to import in a function, since otherwise you should do cyclic imports.